# How to make ASP.NET Core 5 app show its console window on program startup in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net-core, debugging, logging, console, visual-studio-2022

In VS2019, when I start my ASP.NET Core 5 app (which just exposes an API), a console window pops up for that app. There used to be some setting to decide whether to run it as a console / standalone app or host it in IIS Express. I always preferred the console / standalone version because it lets me see the logs in real-time.

In VS2022, however, when I start the very same project, no window appears at all, and, interestingly, neither do I see IIS Express starting up.

How can I get back to having the project start as a console app? (Other than starting it from the command-line and then attaching the debugger.)

---

I just noticed that, strangely, **a minimized console window is being created** and because I start a dozen projects (microservices), I didn't notice it before, and procexplorer told me that the executable had no window, which added to the confusion.

So this is much less problematic, albeit still weird - why does this one particular application not start un-minimized? The only difference it has to all the other executables is that it uses ASP.NET Core while the others (all background services communicating via messagequeue) don't.

This only happens in VS2022, in VS2019 all executables including this one start unminimized.

Comment: all my Blazor server hosting apps started doing that crap. and if the console still exists after rebuild-restart I have to Ctrl+F5 twice till a new tab opens in Browser.

Answer (score 11):

To have VS 2022 open the ASP.NET Core console window *not* minimized, go to:
Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | ASP.NET Core

And unselect 'Launch external console minimized'

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for this. Follow the steps highlighted in in each image:

- Go to your project properties:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then you will see that the console is open in the task bar.
[image]

Comment: I got all that set up. What annoys me is that window starts minimized (it didn't do that in VS2019) and that I don't find a setting to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure, that you selected "IIS Express" as your debug profile

[VS 2022 debug profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28TaJ.png)

Comment: For one, I don't want to run in IISExpress, I want the console window. And I've got the profile selected that's just the project's name. It starts, too - somewhere in the background, I can see the process in TaskManager, but no console window.

Comment: Ok. If you see the Terminal-Window in TaskManager then the windows is maybe out of your monitor range. Click the Termin-Window in TaskManager and press and hold your windows key and then click the arrow left or right to dock the window in range. Maybe this helps.

Comment: no there is no terminal window in my task manager. there is a process with the name of my executable, but that process has no window, as verified with ProcessExplorer

Comment: Ok, sorry for misunderstanding. This is not the same Problem like yours but maybe it has the same core. If so, then VS 2022 has a problem.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2022-debugging-process-starts-but-do/1497966

Answer (score -3):

In Visual Studio 2022 this is currently NOT POSSIBLE