# How to disable the console hiding when I start debugging a .NET project in Visual Studio?

Tags: debugging, console, visual-studio-2022

How can I stop the console from hiding when I start debugging a .NET project in Visual Studio?

Tools → Options → Debugging → "Automatically close the console" is not doing what I want.

Are there any other settings I should use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS2022: how to make ASP.NET Core 5 app show it's console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953657/vs2022-how-to-make-asp-net-core-5-app-show-its-console-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is "Automatically close the console **when debugging stops**". But you want to hide console when **start debugging**, you can try these method:

1.Change Output type to Windows Application in properties:

[image]

2.Add this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3571628/17296043) in the project:

This method will hide the console window when starting debugging.

Here is my test result:

[image]

You can get more information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application).

Comment: May be we didn't understand each other, but my question was about to disable hide console into taskbar icon on debugging start. I would like to keep it visible.

Comment: The real answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76484878/332528